# ¿Cómo obtengo de una cadena definida de tipo string una cadena de números y otra de string en Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Esta es la lista:

```
lista=["(1+2+8+4)/3^4)"]
```

## listanumeros extraída de lista

```
listanumeros=[1,2,8,4,3,4]
```

## listastring extraída de lista

```
listastring=[(,+,+,+,),/,^]
```

¿Cómo lo hago?

Comment: Unas cuantas dudas me asaltan; ¿lista tiene siempre un solo string (como en este caso) o puede tener varios?. ¿En caso de tener varios como debe ser la salida? ¿Puede haber decimales? ¿Puede haber números de más de un dígito (supongo que si)?

Comment: lista=["c 12.33 *  4 + "]   algo como una calculadora cientifica recive varios valorees   de esa lista solo quiero separarlos  por  el tipo  si es numero en una listanumeros  si es caracter  en otra  listastring

Comment: Otra cosa más, si tienes algo como `['(-1+2^-5)']` la listas de strings deberia ser `["-(", "+", "^-"]` o `["-", "(", "+", "^", "-"]` Y por otro lado, si vas usar esto con la idea de parsear la expresíón no te vendría mejor obtener los signos junto al número y no dejarlos en la cadena de string ? Lo digo porque es posible parser los números y obtnerlos con su signo.

Answer (score 3):

Por lo que entiendo, deseas separar de cada string los números (que pueden ser decimales o enteros) de todo lo que no lo es.

En este caso la opción más simple es usar expresiones regulares:

```
import re

lista=["(1+2+8+4)/3^4)", "c12.33*4+"]

patt = re.compile(r"\d*\.?\d+")
listanumeros = [[float(n) for n in patt.findall(cadena)] for cadena  in lista]
listastring  = [patt.split(cadena) for cadena  in lista]
```

La expresíón regular es muy simple:

**`\d`** busca coincidendia con un dígito (de 0 a 9).

**`\.`** coincidencia para el carácter `.`

**`*`** es un cuantificador, busca la coincidencia entre cero y un número ilimitado de veces.

**`?`** es otro cuantificador, pero en este caso la concidencia debe aparecer una vez o no hacerlo.

**`+`** es también un cuantificador, en este caso la coincidencia a de aparecer un mínimo de una vez.

**Salida:**

> >>> print(listanumeros)
>   [[1.0, 2.0, 8.0, 4.0, 3.0, 4.0], [12.33, 4.0]]
>
> >>> print(listastring)
>   [['(', '+', '+', '+', ')/', '^', ')'], ['c', '*', '+']]

Por cada cadena en lista se crea su lista anidada correspondiente en `listanumeros` y `listastring`.

Si quisieras que cada numero sea pasado al tipo de dato que le corresponde (en vez de todos a `float`) puedes hacer algo como:

```
listanumeros = [[float(n) if "." in n else int(n) 
                     for n in patt.findall(cadena)]
                         for cadena  in lista]
```

**Salida**:

> >>> print(listanumeros)
>   [[1, 2, 8, 4, 3, 4], [12.33, 4]]

Si quieres en algún momento obtener los números con su signo correspondiente cambia la expresión regular:

```
patt = re.compile(r"[-+]?\d*\.?\d+")
```

Comment: hermano muchas  gracias

Comment: @ZuiicidaAC de nada, para eso estamos. Ya que eres nuevo por [es.so] te aconsejo mirarte [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) . Saludos.

Answer (score 2):

No te compliques la vida, usa listas por comprensión.
Predefine una función para determinar si la representación de un carácter es un número o no. Yo he usado una sencilla, que intenta representar un entero, si no es un numero devuelve una excepción ValueError, en consecuencia siendo un carácter no entero.

```
def es_numero(x):
    try:
        int(x)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False
```

Finalmente sólo tienes que usar las listas por comprensión de python con este filtro selectivo. Fíjate que tienes una lista con un solo elemento que es la cadena, puedes convertirla o simplemente recorrer el elemento de esta cadena (lista[0]). Cada elemento de la lista se recorre, se aplica el filtro y se guarda en la lista por comprensión resultante si es el caso.

```
[x for x in lista[0] if es_numero(x)]
>>> ['1', '2', '8', '4', '3', '4']
```

I si quieres los no digitos, simplemente niegas la expresión

```
[x for x in lista[0] if es_numero(x)]
>>> ['(', '+', '+', '+', ')', '/', '^', ')']
```